# How to find elements in XML based on where you are in the hierarchy

Tags: xslt

I have a rather complex XML structure but in a small section I have a list of in/out times in the following structure and the potential data it may contain:

```
<EventSummary>
   <Name>In/Out times</Name>
   <Entries>
      <Entry>
         <Name>In</Name>
         <Time>4/1/2013 10:45</Time>
         <Value>1</Value>
      </Entry>
      <Entry>
         <Name>In</Name>
         <Time>4/1/2013 10:55</Time>
         <Value>1</Value>
      </Entry>
      <Entry>
         <Name>Out</Name>
         <Time>4/1/2013 11:30</Time>
         <Value>0</Value>
      </Entry>
      <Entry>
         <Name>In</Name>
         <Time>4/1/2013 11:35</Time>
         <Value>1</Value>
      </Entry>
   </Entries>
</EventSummary>
```

So the entries are guaranteed to be in chronological order but I need to coordinate an In time with the next Out time. So in the example above notice we have an In time followed by another In tim and then an Out time followed by and In time. What I need the final product to look like, in this case is this:

```
<Table>
  <Row>
    <Cell>
      <Text>4/1/2013 10:45</Text>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
      <Text>4/1/2013 11:30</Text>
    </Cell>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Cell>
      <Text>4/1/2013 11:35</Text>
    </Cell>
  </Row>
</Table>
```

Basically I need a Row for each in/out pair. So I need to find the first In, then skip all the next Ins until the first Out, then if another In is found after the Out start a new row...and so on.

I just can't figure out how to switch from looking for an In or an Out while looping through the Entries. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Table>
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select="EventSummary/Entries
                   /Entry[Name = 'In' and 
                          (not(preceding-sibling::Entry) or
                            preceding-sibling::Entry[1]/Name = 'Out')]" />
    </Table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Entry[Name = 'In']">
    <Row>
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select="Time |
                following-sibling::Entry[Name = 'Out'][1]/Time" />
    </Row>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Time">
    <Cell>
      <Text>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </Text>
    </Cell>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<Table>
  <Row>
    <Cell>
      <Text>4/1/2013 10:45</Text>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
      <Text>4/1/2013 11:30</Text>
    </Cell>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Cell>
      <Text>4/1/2013 11:35</Text>
    </Cell>
  </Row>
</Table>
```